# $r_1, ..., r_n$ nonnegative reals, and $x_1,...,x_n$ real numbers then $\sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n \min(r_i, r_j)x_ix_j \geq 0$

Tags: integration, summation, solution-verification, contest-math

Problem Statement:

(a) Show that min$(a, b) = \int_0^{\infty}1_{\leq a}(t)1_{\leq b}(t) dt$ for any nonnegative real numbers $a,b \geq 0$.

(b) Show that if $r_1, ..., r_n$ are nonnegative reals, and $x_1,...,x_n$ are real numbers then
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n \min(r_i, r_j)x_ix_j \geq 0$$

I wanted to see if my solution below was complete. Any feedback on rigor is greatly appreciated:

(a) Suppose WLOG $a \leq b$. The we just have to show that the integral is equal to $a$. We have $\int_0^{\infty}1_{\leq a}(t)1_{\leq b}(t) dt = \int_0^{a}1_{\leq a}(t)1_{\leq b}(t) dt + \int_a^{\infty}1_{\leq a}(t)1_{\leq b}(t) dt = \int_0^{a}1 dt + \int_a^{\infty}0 dt = a$ as desired.

(b) We can use part (a) to convert the desired sum into an integral. We have:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n \min(r_i, r_j)x_ix_j&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n\left(\int_0^{\infty}1_{\leq r_i}(t)1_{\leq r_j}(t) dt \right)x_ix_j\\
&=\int_0^{\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n1_{\leq r_i}(t)x_i1_{\leq r_j}(t)x_j dt\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n1_{\leq r_i}(t)x_i\right)\left(\sum_{j = 1}^n1_{\leq r_j}(t)x_j \right)dt\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n1_{\leq r_i}(t)x_i\right)^2dt\\
&\geq 0
\end{align}
as desired.

Comment: Looks fine. $\phantom{\text{What would be an answer?..}}$